# The hangman game backward #5

Tags: riddle, english, language, letters

Hangman game backward version 5 ([Aggie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16798/the-hangman-game-backwards-again)'s version was #4) - guess what was the question:

fill in an "a" - It's a lethal to throw and it's destructive.
fill in a  "d" - It's brave, and it's **strong**.
fill in an "e" - It's brown, and it's reddish-brown.
fill in a  "t" - It's fast, and it's fastening

Again, your answer can be in the form of:

> The question was: _ p p l e

followed by explanation.

Now, I know it's an easy one, hence I will not accept any answer that does not explains all **8** answers.

Comment: You didn't count [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16790/5373) as a "Hangman game backward" then?

Comment: @randal'thor ahh I didn't see it, the title isn't obvious enough to catch my eye hehe!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was

> b o l _

It's lethal to throw and it's destructive

> **bola**, which is both a South American throwing weapon and a volcano in Papua New Guinea (which can be destructive).

It's brave, and it's strong

> **bold**, which is a synonym for brave as well as the common term for **strong text**.

It's brown, and it's reddish-brown

> **bole**, which is the trunk of a tree (hence brown) and a shade of reddish-brown on its own.

It's fast, and it's fastening

> **bolt**, which is a definition for a fast dash, as well as a piece of hardware used to fasten two things together.

Comment: Seems like a short lived question, nicely done!

Answer (score 7):

> The question was bol_

fill in an "a" - It's a lethal to throw and it's destructive.

> bola - a throwing weapon made of weights on the ends of an interconnected cord

fill in a "d" - It's brave, and it's **strong**.

> bold - bold is a synonym of brave and in bold is strong text

fill in an "e" - It's brown, and it's reddish-brown.

> bole - the trunk or stem of a tree (so it's brown)

fill in a "t" - It's fast, and it's fastening

> bolt - to bolt is to fasten (something) with a metal pin or bar, in particular. Also a flash of lightning (which is fast)

Comment: both are correct answers!  However I will accept Bailey's as it seems to be faster.  I will upvote yours

Comment: Well, I was the first to reply but whatever

Comment: @Alex You must've made a timing error? TroyAndAbed 22:03:07, BaileyM 22:05:36.

Comment: True, TroyAndAbed did get his answer in before me - Alex did say he would only accept an answer that explained all 8 answers though, and this one missed a couple!